# kivy android app: Set the api level from 19 to 26 failed

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I want to create an android .apk file with kivy, buildozer and Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I had an android .apk but google playstore said, that the api level of 19 is not available. I have to set it on 26. Now i set the android.api to 26 in the buildozer.spec file. After running this for creating a new .apk file with an api level of 26 i get the following problem:

```
[INFO]: Avaiable API's are (19)
[WARNING]: Request API target 26 is not available, install it with the SDK and android tool.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android update sdk
2. Select *API 26*
3. Run ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android
4. Select *Android SDK Build-tools 26.x.x*
5. Check *aidl* file in `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/26.x.x/`

Comment: I installed API 26,27,28 and the newest version of the building tool. In buildozer.spec i set android.api = 26 and get this error: Check that aidl cam be executed --> Search for Aidl --> Run 'home/dennis/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/28.0.2/aidl' --> CWD None --> Aidl cannot be executed ..... do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: Run ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android and select Android  SDK Build tools 26.x.x